# how to hide the subform vertical edge

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access form which consist of many subforms ; the problem is that each subform has unwanted edge as shown in the following pic :

[image]

i want to hide this edge for each subform to reduce the form space ;i don't know if there any way to remove this edge just need any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These can be disabled by turning off **Record Selectors** in the form's properties.

- Open the form in design view.
- View the form's properties.
- Under the **Format** tab, change the setting of the **Record Selectors** to NO.
- Save the form.